# Is it possible to retrieve the angle of a LinearGradientBrush in code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, lineargradientbrush

I'm looking at the constructor for the LinearGradientBrush class and I see it has an override which takes a collection of GradientStops and a double as an angle.

When I look at the properties of it, I can't find how to get the angle form the brush once it's been defined.

Is there a way to do this, or am I going to have to write some function which looks at the Start and End points and calculates the angle from those? (Blech - please do not tell me that is my only option...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't find how to get the angle form the brush once it's been defined.

According to [referencesource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationCore/Core/CSharp/System/Windows/Media/LinearGradientBrush.cs,825a04264073b925), `angle` is not stored, but just used to calculate `EndPoint`:

```
public LinearGradientBrush(GradientStopCollection gradientStopCollection,
                           double angle) : base (gradientStopCollection)
{
    EndPoint = EndPointFromAngle(angle);
}

private Point EndPointFromAngle(double angle)
{
     // Convert the angle from degrees to radians
     angle = angle * (1.0/180.0) * System.Math.PI;

     return (new Point(System.Math.Cos(angle), System.Math.Sin(angle)));            
}
```

Getting `angle` from `EndPoint` should be straightforward.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to get/set an angle based on a double from 0.0D to 1.0D? ( I suppose I should ask that as another question... )

Comment: I'm afraid I did not get it.

Comment: It's fine. I think I have an idea thanks for your help.